# Is there a variable type for the constant in a "case" in the switch-case?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Lets say we have :

```
unsigned char test;
test=0xff;

switch (test)
  {
  case -1:
    cout<<"hit 1";
    break;
  case 255:
    cout<<"hit 2";
    break;    
  }
```

Why it gives out "hit 2" while -1 could be represent as 0xff in memory for a unsigned char.
Is there a type for the constant (here -1 and 255) in a "case" in the switch-case?
As far as i know, without the variable types, we cannot compare two variables.

Comment: What wasn't clear from the answers you got, last time asking it?!?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually "how does switch-case handle the value of the constant in a "case"?" was asked by me, but I decided to close that question because that was not a good question.

Comment: @henryyao: It's true this question is much clearer, but the other already had very good answers.

Comment: @henryyao You should update your other question then to improve it. That's not very polite regarding the efforts some people invested to write answers for you (and those well apply to this question as good).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard says:

> 6.4.2    The switch statement      `[stmt.switch]`
>
> 1. The switch statement causes control to be transferred to one of several statements depending on the value of a condition.
> 2. The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or class type.  If of class type, the condition is contextually implicitly converted (Clause 4) to an integral or enumeration type.  **Integral promotions are performed.**   Any  statement  within  the  switch  statement  can  be  labeled  with  one  or  more  case  labels  as
>      follows:
>
>    `case` *`constant-expression`* `:`
>
> > > > where the *constant-expression* shall be a converted constant expression (5.19) **of the promoted type of the switch condition**.  No two of the case constants in the same switch shall have the same value after conversion to the promoted type of the switch condition.

The data type is `int`, because all smaller integral types promote to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `unsigned char` goes from 0-255 you have overflow.